# How did overflow actually work here?

Tags: css, overflow

I had this central div which had varying content length based on the tab selected in navigation bar. I gave the div a minimum height expecting it to adjust accordingly as per the content length. I also set the height property to auto. This did not work. But adding overflow:hidden solved the problem. I really fail to understand how this actually worked.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

```
.central{
width: 70%;
min-height: 700px;
height: auto;
margin: 20px auto;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 20px -5px #CFCFCF, -2px -2px 20px -5px #CFCFCF;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

**EDIT:**
Apologies if I wasn't able to explain my problem correctly.
What was happening without overflow:hidden is that the content within the central div was flowing out of the div, but after using it the height of central div seems to have been adjusted so as to accommodate the content. The relevant css and markup are as follows -

```
.central{
width: 70%;
min-height: 700px;
height: auto;
margin: 20px auto;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
/*border: 1px solid #C6C6C6;*/
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 20px -5px #CFCFCF, -2px -2px 20px -5px #CFCFCF;
overflow: hidden;
}

.main_content{
width: inherit;
height: inherit;
}

.main_content img{
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}

#content1{
margin: 20px;
}

.img{
width: 25%;
height: 25%;
margin: 20px;
float: left;
}

.desc{
width: 65%;
height: auto;
min-height: 650px;
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
margin-top: 20px;
font-family: 'Aleor';
font-size: 100%;
}

.desc p:last-child{
padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

The HTML

```
<div class="central">
    <section id="content1">
        <div class="main_content">
            <article class="img"><img src="profile.jpg"/></article>
            <section class="desc">
                <p>The content</p>
            </section>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post a complete code example, not a single CSS rule.

Comment: Do you have floating elements within `.central`??

Comment: What did not work? your central has a min height of 700, if your content is not 700 px high, the container will still have a height of 700

Comment: "I gave the div a minimum height expecting it to adjust accordingly as per the content length."
That's not true. A max-height will do, until size matches max-height.

Comment: @LinkinTED You should probably post that as an answer.  That's the only explanation I can think of for the described behavior.

Comment: a codepen.io example would be amazing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also commented this.

You probably have floating elements that cause the problem. You can fix it by using `overflow: auto`.

By using that, the container recognizes that there are elements inside it.

**UPDATE**

Check the [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/Gkhb9/) on how `overflow:auto` works with floated children.

Answer (score 0):

`overflow: hidden;` **prevents** any content from **displaying outside of its parent's container**.

In this situation, the content most likely did not fill up the `min-height` of `700px` and therefore had extra whitespace.  This was only able to be shrunk through `overflow: hidden;` (shrinkwrapping the content) or decreasing the `min-height`.

Comment: `overflow: hidden` would not cause an element with a `min-height` to shrink.